# Let G be a group with identity $e$. If $a,b$ are integers, and $x$ is an element in G such that $x^a=e$ and $x^b=e$, then show that $x^{gcd(a,b)}=e$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm not really sure how to start this proof. 
Should I start with 3 different cases, $a=b, a<b, a>b$?

If $a=b$, then of course $gcd(a,b)=a=b$ and so $x^{gcd(a,b)}=x^a=x^b=e.$

If $a<b$, then...

Any suggestions would help, I'm pretty stuck, thanks.

Comment: Look at Bézout's identity.

Comment: How familiar are you with the ideas of Euclid's algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

You can always express the $GCD(y,z) = Ay +Bz$, where $A$ and $B$ are integers, by Bezout's identity. This means that $x^{GCD(y,z)}= x^{Ax+By}= x^{Ay}x^{Bz}= e^Ae^B=e$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little confused with your solution. Could you please explain the steps to me?

Comment: Say for example, a= 5 b=7, then the gcd is 1, meaning if $x^5=e=x^7$ then $x^1=e$. 1 (the gcd) can be written as A5+B7 that is $1= 3*5 + (-2)7$ so that $x^1 = x^{3*5 -2*7}=(x^5)^3(x^7)^{-2}= e^3e^{-2} =e$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The kernel of $\Bbb Z\to G$, $n\mapsto x^n$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, hence of the form $m\Bbb Z$.